# Understanding Merge Sort

Tags: java, sorting

Following is my java implementation of merge sort, which I did after attending a tutorial on merge sort algorithm.

```
package com.test.sort;

import java.util.Scanner;


    ////100 80 90 70 60 40 50 30 10 20 //1 3 5 4 2
    public class MergeSortTest {

        private static int[] dataIntAry;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Enter data to be sorted : ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String data = scanner.nextLine();


            String[] dataAry = data.split("\\ ");

            dataIntAry = new int[dataAry.length];

            int cnt = 0;
            for (String dataEntity : dataAry) {
                dataIntAry[cnt] = Integer.parseInt(dataEntity);
                cnt++;
            }
            System.out.println("Array to operate on.");
            print(dataIntAry);
            System.out.println("===================================================================");

            sort(dataIntAry);


            System.out.println("###############################FINAL################################");

            print(dataIntAry);


        }



        private static void sort(int[] array) {

            performMergeSort(0, array.length-1);

        }

        private static void performMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
            System.out.println("Operating on array: ");
            print(dataIntAry, lowerIndex, higherIndex);

            //sort only if there is more than one elment in the array
            if(lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
                int middle = lowerIndex + ((higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2);


                performMergeSort(lowerIndex,middle);

                performMergeSort(middle+1, higherIndex);

                merge(lowerIndex,higherIndex);

            }


        }

        private static void merge(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

            System.out.println("Merging array: ");
            print(dataIntAry, lowerIndex, higherIndex);

            for(int i=lowerIndex; i<=higherIndex; i++) {
                for(int j=i+1; j<=higherIndex; j++) {
                    if(dataIntAry[i] > dataIntAry[j]) {
                        int temp = dataIntAry[i];
                        dataIntAry[i] = dataIntAry[j];
                        dataIntAry[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("After Merge: ");
            print(dataIntAry, lowerIndex, higherIndex);

        }


        private static void print(int[] dataIntAry){
            System.out.println();
            for(int val: dataIntAry){
                System.out.print(val + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        private static void print(int[] dataIntAry, int startIndex, int endIndex){
            Systegivingrintln();

            int index = 0;
            for(int val: dataIntAry){
                if(index >= startIndex && index <= endIndex)
                    System.out.print(val + " ");

                index++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

This code sorts the array provided at run time. First of all I doubt if the implementation is corect or not!. If the implementation is correct, I am really suspicious about its performance. **How do i really ensure that the implementation is giving a worst case performance of O(n log n)?**
The main fishy part here is the **merge()** method where I do a comapre and swap!.

Comment: can I know the reason for negative voting? I can make changes accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't look like a typical merge sort.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ok. That really is my question. Why do you think so?

Comment: merge() should happen in O(n) since the two halves are already individually sorted. In the code in the post, this is not the case.

Comment: @JagrutSharma Yes. I have mentioned that in my question too. how do you think I can modify the merge() to make that happen?

Comment: merge() should take two arrays, and combine them into one sorted array - this will take linear time.

Comment: @JagrutSharma lets say my final arrays are [1,2,3,8] & [4,5,6,7]. Individually they are in sorted order. But while merging, '8' has to come at the end. How do I do it without comparison?

Comment: You would maintain two pointers i and j, one for each array A and B. Allocate space for the result array C = size(A) + size (B). Compare A[i] and B[j] and put the smaller value in C. Increment the index for the array  which got its value put in C. Keep going till you are done with both arrays. Any remaining values in A or B go at the end of C. This will take linear time and give you C which is sorted.

Comment: @JagrutSharma Thank you. that makes a lot of sense. Got to improve my logical skills!!.

Answer (score 1):

From your code I think your merging part is incorrect. You should merge based on lower, middle and higher index. Use below method call

```
mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
```

instead of

```
merge(lowerIndex,higherIndex);
```

User below function

```
private void mergeParts(int lowerIndex, int middle, int higherIndex) {

        for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++) {
            tempMergArr[i] = array[i];
        }
        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = lowerIndex;
        while (i <= middle && j <= higherIndex) {
            if (tempMergArr[i] <= tempMergArr[j]) {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while (i <= middle) {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Complexity of Merge sort is O(nlogn)

Because merge sort divides the array in two halves at each stage which gives it log(n) component and the other N component comes from its comparisons that are made at each stage. So combining it becomes nearly O(nlog n).

Comment: Well, I found it lil complicated to understand here. http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/merge-sort/
SO thought of writing my own logic. An explanation can help.